# NCURSES stdin in C

Tags: c, ncurses

For some reason **ncurses** does not like **stdin**, I know I could use instead getstr(), here it is what I'm doing so far,

```
while (fgets(str, BUF, stdin) != NULL) {
    printf("input something ");
}
```

How could I get an alternative to stdin for this loop (perhaps using getstr())?

Any help will be appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Is there anything in particular you're looking for that makes `getstr()` an inferior option?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getstr() to read from stdin to a buffer. Check the curses [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO) for examples.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main() {
   char buf[80];

   initscr();   

   do {
      getstr(buf);
      mvprintw(5, 0, "You entered: %s", buf);
   } while (strcmp(buf, "STOP"));

   endwin();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For capturing input using ncurses, I would use one of the 3 functions based upon your needs:

getch() for characters, scanw() for formatted input and finally getstr()